# What is the purpose of using span except of div?

Tags: html

I want to know the purpose of using span container instead of div container. Where should i create the div and where the span.

I don't know. I just want the answer of my question.

Comment: span is an inline element, div is a block-level element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` is a logical division of content, so it's better suited for grouping related content. A `span` is generally used to mark and/or style content within a larger block. A `div` is generally `display: block` by default, whereas a `span` is `display: inline`.

The snippet below demonstrates a very common usage:

```css
.important {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Repellendus fuga <span class="important">facere quia perferendis</span> aut voluptas laboriosam ut provident distinctio soluta sint et.
</div>
```